# The fans in my MacBook Pro (2007) run at full speed for no reason?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

For some reason the fans in my MacBook Pro *(2007 model)* seem to run at full speed for no apparent reason, I've been using the ["iStats" gem](https://github.com/Chris911/iStats) to monitor my temps and fan speeds - what's strange is that the CPU temperature often sits around *40 - 45°C* even when the fans are running around the *2000RPM* mark - yet occasionally, for some odd reason it decides to boost them up to *5000RPM+*. I'll just be happily browsing the web and all of a sudden it decides its time for takeoff...

[image: CPU Temp & Fan Speed, iStats Terminal View]

Anybody know a reason or possible fix for this? I've considered using some software to control the fan speed manually though I don't want to do anything that might potentially cause the system overheat.

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trouble with fan speeds can almost always be solved by resetting the System Management Controller, or SMC.

> After performing normal troubleshooting, these symptoms may indicate that an SMC reset could be necessary.
>
> **Fans**
>
> - The computer's fans run at high speed although the computer is not experiencing heavy usage and is properly ventilated.

<sup>Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964</sup>

The procedure for laptops with removable batteries is as follows:

> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Disconnect the MagSafe power adapter from the computer, if it's connected.
> 3. Remove the battery.
> 4. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds.
> 5. Release the power button.
> 6. Reconnect the battery and MagSafe power adapter.
> 7. Press the power button to turn on the computer.

<sup>Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a shot and see if it works!

Comment: UPDATE : Fans seem to be working normally, I'll give it a little while to see how things go - fingers crossed that this worked!

Comment: UPDATE 2 : Fans seem to be much quieter and certainly slower. - Thanks for this!

Comment: Since this appeared in search results in 2022, here is the updated link to the support page on SMC reset for Intel machines: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295